# Regex for only if if a character is present then it can be succeeded

Tags: regex

I am trying to construct a simple regex for detecting URLs. My progress is this regex:
`^((https?):\/\/)?[\w.]*[\w]+\.[a-z]{3}\/?([\w\?\#.=-]+\/?)*$` But this is not actually what I want.
This can detect URLs like:

`https://something.com`

`www.stackoverflow.com`

`subdomain.domain.com/something/photo.png`

But this also detects

`subdomain.domain.communication`

My goal is this:

There must be three characters in the domain ending (.com, .org, .net). There can be a `/` or not after the domain ending. But if only a `/` is present it should look into futher regex else it shold not match. Like it should detect:

`https://somewebsite.com`

`https://somewebsite.com/`

`https://somewebsite.com/webpage/some#section`

But not:

`https://something.commmm/`

Comment: I suggest you use regex101.com to test regular expression.  And consult the section `BNF for specific URL schemes` in RFC1738.

Comment: How is this question related to `java` here?

Comment: Actually, I have to implement the regex in both js and Java. Nevertheless, removed the tags to make the question specific

Comment: @thesamiroli `subdomain.domain.communication` is a valid url.  The only reason it will not work is because there is no `communication` top level domain.

Comment: @DominiqueFortin But what want is that there should be exactly 3 letters in a domain ending.

Comment: @thesamiroli Try `^(https?:\/\/)?([\w]+\.)+[a-z]{3}(\/[\w\?\#.=-]+)*\/?$`

Comment: @DominiqueFortin Thank you so much. Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`^(https?:\/\/)?([\w]+\.)+[a-z]{3}(\/[\w\?\#.=-]+)*\/?$`

Comment: Please edit your answer to exactly match your comment. There are unescaped characters in your answer.